# After rewind(), can you make fprintf() write to end of file (e.g. complete overwrite)

Tags: c, file, io, overwrite

In C, the `rewind()` call starts the next write at the front of the file.

As I understand it, when I call `fprintf()`, it will write to the end of the string I am trying to write and no further.  If the existing file has data past the end of the string I am writing, this is not overwritten.

Is there a way to change this behavior so that `rewind()` can be used to effectively perform a quick overwrite of the entire file?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to truncate the file to zero length, reopen it in write mode. If you want to truncate it while it's open, `ftruncate` should do it in POSIX systems. There are, I believe, `_chsize` and `_ftruncate` in Windows, which are similar.